# String.split replication: OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, split, chatbot

For my `CompSci` class, we're making a *Would You Rather?* function for our chatbot project. The `String.split()` method works well for this, but we get bonus points if we can do it without it. I decided to go about this by just creating a method that replicated `String.split`.

```
private String[] separate (String phrase, String omit1, String omit2)
{
    int c = 0;

    //gets rid of leading and trailing whitespace, replaces target characters
    //with the # character
    phrase = phrase.trim();
    phrase = phrase.replace(omit1, "#");
    phrase = phrase.replace(omit2, "#");

    //detects the number of phrases to be included in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
        if (phrase.charAt(i) == '#')
            c++;

    //creates array list based on number of phrases
    String[] phraseList = new String[c];
    c = 0;

    //builds phrases from characters found between occurrences
    //of the # character
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        if (phrase.charAt(i) == '#')
            c++;
        else if (phrase.charAt(i) != '#')
            phraseList[c] += phrase.charAt(i);
    }

    return phraseList;

}
```

Whenever I use this method with the phrase "Would you rather have tea, eat cookie, or push up?" (omit1 being "," and omit2 being "or") it throws this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Magpie.separate(Magpie.java:306)
    at Magpie.getResponse(Magpie.java:44)
    at MagpieRunner.main(MagpieRunner.java:24)
```

I realize that this has something to do with the counter for the `phraseList` array, but my attempts to fix it have so far been to no avail.

Any Help?

Comment: The last `if-else-if` should just be an `if-else`, because you are simply checking the same condition twice, the second time negating it. Also, this is a classic [Off by one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). See answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because if you have even 1 # you will have 2 strings so you need to do c+1 while creating a new array

Like

```
//creates array list based on number of phrases
String[] phraseList = new String[c+1];
c = 0;
```

you should use `replaceAll(omit1,"#")` and not `replace(omit1,"#")` & `replace(omit2,"#")`

Can you give more information on where the null is coming ?

Edit:

Have you tried something like ?

```
phraseList[0]="";
for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
  {
     if(phrase.charAt(i) == '#')
     {
        c++;
        phraseList[c]="";
     }else if(phrase.charAt(i) != '#')
     {
        phraseList[c] += phrase.charAt(i);
     }
  }
```

Comment: That worked nicely, but when the response returns, there's a "null" in front of it. Any pointers?

Comment: When I use the phrase "Would you rather have tea, eat cookie, or push up?" the array's values are nullhave tea, null eat cookie, and null push up.

Comment: Assuming you are splitting on , right ? and the expected output is Would you rather have tea as first eat cookie as second and or push up? as third ?

Comment: Yes, all occurrences of "," and "or" are replaced by "#" and ignored when building new values for phraseList. The expected output options are "have tea", " eat cookie", and " push up?"(before I call the method, "Would you rather " is deleted from the string).

Comment: Yes! This almost solved the issue, but "have tea" is still "nullhave tea".

Comment: That might be an issue with the place where you are removing "Would you rather "

Comment: I'm using statement.replace("Would you rather", ""); to remove "Would you rather." I get "nullhavetea" both ways...

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like commas separating a list:

```
1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6
```

If you count the commas, you'll find there are five; but there are six entries in the list. That's because commas separate the entries, but you still have one on each end.

Or think in terms of fence posts and panels: five posts, four panels.

When you create your array to store the phrases, you need one more entry than you had split points, to make sure you have room for all the phrases.

But it would be easier to avoid this entirely and return a `List<String>` rather than a `String[]`. That way, you don't need to know the size in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since other answers showed you what's wrong with your code, here is a cleaner way of separating string that you might like and that behaves more like the actual `split()` method:

```
private String[] separate(String phrase, String delim) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

    // add delimiter to the end of the string
    // so last token will be included properly
    phrase += delim;

    // start from index of first deliminator
    // i is the index for the deliminator
    // j is the index for the first char of the expression before deliminator
    int i, j = 0;

    // while there are deliminators
    while( (i = phrase.indexOf(delim, j)) != -1)  {
        // obtain the current token from j to deliminator location
        String token = phrase.substring(j, i);
        // trim leading/trailing spaces of the token and make sure it has any chars
        // if it does, add the token to list
        if(token.trim().length() != 0) {
            tokens.add(token);
        }
        // update j to the first character after the deliminator
        j = i + delim.length();
    }

    return tokens.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: There is a reason `toArray()` with no parameters exists; that's to avoid having to write `toArray(new SomeType[0])` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

why not use StringTokenizer? (Below is an example from Java doc)

The following is one example of the use of the tokenizer. The code:

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

prints the following output:

```
 this
 is
 a
 test
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed starting from 0, but the length of the array is determined with an initial value of 1.

So even though `c` gives you the number of phrases, its actually the number of indices in the array (since `c` starts from 0) and not the actual length. The actual length will be c + 1 (since length is calculated starting from 1)

```
Index     0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
Length    1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

For example, if c = 4 (Index = 4), your String[] will have length 4, when it should be 5. This is what throws that ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Hope this helps :)